# How to override generic table inheritance in a ASP MasterPage in UI controls that generate tables

Tags: css, asp.net

We have a masterpage that the admin has required all CSS to be linked from. The issue I'm having seems to be because he defined css for tables and those settings are overriding a separate CSS file dedicated to formatting GridView and DetailsView Controls. I tried overriding the site wide "table" CSS, but because he is forcing me to link the UI controls CSS on the masterpage, it of course, overrides his default table style as well.

1. Is it correct to have the CSS for controls that do not appear on most pages in the masterpage or should it be referenced in the individual page?

If the former is correct:

2. Is there a way to have both a generic table CSS that applies to all tables but has a separate table CSS for asp.net controls in the same masterpage?

```css
.GridView-Header a, th {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
    color: white;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

Comment: ASP.Net controls render as HTML. As far as CSS is concerned, a `Gridview` is the same thing as a `table`. If you want a global style for all tables, put it in the master page. If you want that overridden on certain pages, or certain gridviews, then use a class instead of targeting the element.

Comment: I moved the css link to the target page back out of the master. Do you have an example? The issue is partially resolved, but I am running into issues with ASP specific controls. As they use the CssClass tag to select the class, I cannot target things like sortable headers which generate <a> tags for the header links. Those get overridden by :any-link and If I selectively override :any-link in the page then the rest of the generated menus in the header are incorrect.

Comment: Got it sorted. I had the a referenced in the wrong gridview element... I added my css above for posterity, or something :) ...